# Marklogic App server 8001- connection Refused Error

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, xquery-3.0, marklogic-7

I have installed MarkLogic server on the Windows operating system. I am able to access the query console and Dashboard applications. However, I cannot access the admin server on port 8001. I receive a connection refused error.

Can someone help me figure out why I could connect to the nav dashboard and query console, but not the admin server?

I restarted the services and then uninstalled and reinstalled the software too.

Comment: I'd start with looking for the ErrorLog.txt file, which is located at `c:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Logs\ErrorLog.txt` on Windows. It could be that 8001 is occupied by a different service. The ErrorLog should report such issues..

Comment: Info: App-Services: Unable to create links, 'Admin' App Server does not exist.  Check configuration.
Info: Manage: Unable to create links, 'Admin' App Server does not exist.  Check configuration.

Comment: I am seeing the above error when I opened the error logs.txt .please let me know if I need to configure the new server ? incase how can I configure the new admin portal?

Comment: Your local installation seems broken. Was this an upgrade, or a clean install?

Answer (score 1):

If you can access Query Console, then you could execute the following script to use [`admin:appserver-set-port`](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:appserver-set-port) to change the Admin server port to a different port that is available (this example sets to port 1234):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
          at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $port := 1234   
let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $groupid := admin:group-get-id($config, "Default")
return 
  admin:save-configuration(
    admin:appserver-set-port(
      $config, 
      admin:appserver-get-id($config, $groupid, "Admin"),
      $port)
  )
```

Comment: I had  used the following query to set the admin port . it was executed successfully.However, when i am navigating to 8001 port it is pointing out to query console again.Hence i uninstalled it completely and  installed with mark logic 8  directly .  My problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it was problem with the upgrade and when I uninstalled. I had used the following query to set the admin port. It was executed successfully. However, when I was navigating to 8001 port it is pointing to 8000 again through query console. Hence I uninstalled it completely and installed with MarkLogic 8 directly. My problem is resolved.